# Copying EXIF from 1 image to another is failing

Tags: c#, exif

I am using something like this:

```
foreach (PropertyItem item in image.PropertyItems)
{
    newImage.SetPropertyItem(item);
}
```

But it is not copying all the EXIF elements. A number of the core "good ones" are missing, like Camera Make and Camera Model. What is causing this?

I would consider using a 3rd party component or libray. But I need it to be free and it has to be able to write EXIF data, as well as extract it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in JPEG only, try ExifUtils (http://code.google.com/p/exif-utils/).
Works very well with a lot of digital camera exif info.